# Return directory file structure in Node JS

Tags: node.js, arrays, function, return

I'm trying to return a file structure from filesystem to present as "directory listing" if no index.html file is found in a webserver.

I have a function that traverse the directory and add the levels to an array

```
function getAllFiles(dirPath){
    var accPath = [];
    fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach(function(file) {
    let filepath = path.join(dirPath , file);
    let stat= fs.statSync(filepath);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {            
      getAllFiles(filepath);
    } else {
          accPath.push(filepath);                  
    } 
}); 
accPath.forEach(elm => {
    // to check that I have traversed directory
    console.log(elm);
})  
return accPath; // returning the directory array 
}
```

I use it in like this:

```
var dirStructure = [];
dirStructure = getAllFiles(filePath);

   console.log("noOfFiles "+dirStructure.length);
   dirStructure.forEach(lmnt => {
        console.log(lmnt);
   })
```

the result is that "getAllFiles" lists

```
public\css\bootstrap.min.css
public\js\bootstrap.min.js
public\js\jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
public\js\popper.min.js
public\index2.html
```

But I only get one element form the "dirStructure" array

```
"noOfFiles 1"
public\index2.html
```

Comment: You are running `getAllFiles(filepath);` but you don't do anything with the result

Comment: so it will not assign the result to  "dirStructure" ?

Comment: I mean the recursive call

Comment: Please explain. From my logs the getAllFiles traverse the file structure. What it doesent do is returning the full array in the return value from the function. It seems to only return one value of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you never do anything with the recursive call

I suggest pushing it into `accPath` like `accPath.push(...getAllFiles(filepath))`

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function getAllFiles(dirPath) {
  const accPath = [];
  fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach(file => {
    const filepath = path.join(dirPath, file);
    const stat = fs.statSync(filepath);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      // you have to use the data returned from getAllFiles
      accPath.push(...getAllFiles(filepath));
    } else {
      accPath.push(filepath);
    }
  });

  return accPath;
}
```